# What does the C mean in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been using this query for a long time and I want to know what does the C means, I couldnt find any anwsers because it's difficult to search for a single letter.

I just want to know what the last C stands for.

```
"...(SELECT COALESCE(MAX(orden), 0) FROM productos C)+ 1"
```

Comment: `C` is saying that if the word C is found in context later in the SQL it is a reference to the table named `productos`. It is an alias for the table named immediately before the first occurance of C in your SQL query.

Comment: Looks like simple alias for table products.

Comment: In that query it means nothing. Sure it is an alias, but never used - somebody forgot to use it :-). Query is exact the same as `(SELECT COALESCE(MAX(C.orden), 0) FROM productos C)`

Comment: @vadim it does. See the link under my answer.

Comment: @Patrick_Hofman OK I see... it is special "hack" for MySQL...  I did not work with it for long time... sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `C` is an alias for table `productos`. You can reference it's columns through the alias.

As an example, you can use `C` in the context of your query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(C.orden), 0) FROM productos C
```

Often using aliases is useful when joining multiple tables with colliding column names.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but if I remove it, it shows me this error:
    1093: You can't specify target table 'productos' for update in FROM clause 011.

Are aliases mandatory in this cases?

Comment: Not that I know but you didn't show your entire query either.

Comment: This is the entire Query:

$sql = "INSERT INTO productos (nombre, categoria_id, descripcion, activo, destacado, url, orden) VALUES ('$nombre', '$tipo', '$descripcion', '$activo', '$destacado', '$url', (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(orden), 0) FROM productos C WHERE categoria_id='$tipo')+ 1)";

Comment: Yeah. I see. See the post linked in my previous comment about the why.